# How to let this SVG graphic fit to its container automatically?

Tags: html, css, svg

http://jsfiddle.net/K5RYY/

I have a SVG star in the demo. It's inside a `div` with a given width and height. How can I make the graphics automatically fit the size of that wrapper div? I think it's possible because it's a vector graphic.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `viewBox="0 0 230 230"` to your SVG it will redimension according to your DIV.

See an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/K5RYY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `viewBox="15 15 200 190" preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the svg element. [viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) contains x y width and height values and defines the area you can see.

If you want the star to keep its aspect ratio at the expense of some space at the edges in one dimension then you can adjust the preserveAspectRatio value.

Comment: Would you please explain more details about the numbers in the answer? Thanks!